# Android app SQLiteDatabase inserting new values not working, 0 errors in code

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I'm making an Android app and I got some done solution from androidhive which has a database etc, so I'm trying to add more values into that database e.g address, telephone etc, but whenever I make a new string in the code, the app isn't working...

For example now I just wanna read the values from the database to show my account info(which I inserted from my website registration form and account info works perfecty fine in there)

My database handler class for reading the info:

```
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login";
// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";


public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("fname", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("lname", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("uname", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(6));
            /*user.put("address", cursor.getString(7));
            user.put("tel", cursor.getString(8));
            user.put("ptc", cursor.getString(9));
            user.put("dob", cursor.getString(10));*/
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }
```

As you can see this commented part is what I want to add in the app so it reads those values in the app.
This is my profile.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile);


        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        user = db.getUserDetails();

        /**
         * Displays the account details in Text view
         **/

        final TextView fname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fname);
        final TextView lname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lname);
        final TextView uname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.uname);
        final TextView email = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.email);
        final TextView address = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);
        final TextView tel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tel);
        final TextView ptc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ptc);
        final TextView dob = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dob);
        final TextView created_at = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.regat);
        fname.setText(user.get("fname"));
        lname.setText(user.get("lname"));
        uname.setText(user.get("uname"));
        email.setText(user.get("email"));
        address.setText(user.get("address"));
        tel.setText(user.get("tel"));
        ptc.setText(user.get("ptc"));
        dob.setText(user.get("dob"));
        created_at.setText(user.get("created_at")); }}
```

This is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE `login`.`member` (   
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
`encrypted_password` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,    
`email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
`fname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
`lname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
`dob` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
`tel` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,  
`address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`ptc` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
`salt` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL   
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Remember, it works perfectly fine on the website, and btw, when I try to add these extra strings into the registration in the app, it happens the same(app stops working) and when I don't add anything new in the app code, only when I leave it like it's now(with commented added part) it works perfectly and reads first name, last name, username, email, created at.

What could be the problem in here? Is it the database? The .java code? My API?

Comment: What does `selectQuery` contains?

Comment: @LS_dev I posted my table too, it's the last part of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is `login` and you are referring to a table named `login`.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN; // table name is 'login'
```

But you created a table in `login` database with name `member`.

```
CREATE TABLE `login`.`member`
```

Obviously it should not be working.

And even if you have a typo error, based on your `select` statement, your `cursor.getString` sequences are wrong.

When you are selecting *all* fields by specifying `*`, you must abide by the sequence order number of the columns to use in `getString` methods.

If I am not wrong, they shall be:

```
user.put("uid", cursor.getString(1)); // id - uid
user.put("username", cursor.getString(2)); // uname - username
user.put("email", cursor.getString(4));
user.put("fname", cursor.getString(5));
user.put("lname", cursor.getString(6));
user.put("dob", cursor.getString(7));
user.put("tel", cursor.getString(8));
user.put("address", cursor.getString(9));
user.put("ptc", cursor.getString(10));
user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(12));
```

Comment: but tell me why is it working without adding anything into the code? and I tried to name the table 'member' as it's its name, and it didn't work anyhow

Comment: @Simon_says: May be you are connected to a *different* database i.e. other than `login` database. Check your db  connection string.

Comment: it's the same database, cause when I make an account on my website, I can login with the same information in the android app

Comment: this is the logcat: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 7 from CursorWindow. Make sure the cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it."

Comment: @Simon_says: I still suggest you to look into database connection parameters.

Comment: `define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "password");
define("DB_DATABASE", "login");`
 `public function connect() {
        require_once 'include/config.php';
        // connecting to mysql
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        // selecting database
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
        // return database handler
        return $con;
    }`
This is my API...

Comment: @Simon_says: Then you should correctly post the `login.login` table fields information. Not the `member` table.

Comment: I got only 1 database on my server, and 1 table in it, whose name is 'member', and my API works by calling member, and it doesn't make sense to me that when I change LOGIN_TABLE name to 'member' the app doesn't find it, it only (partially) works when the name is 'login'

Comment: @Simon_says: Try changing `select` statement to include database name, like `login.login` or `login.member`, and see if any of them works.

Comment: btw I followed this tutorial http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/08/develop-android-login-registration-with-php-mysql.html and his database name isn't "login" and his LOGIN_TABLE name is login. Here is the full code of my app, maybe it will be more helpful to understand...

Comment: I partially have gone through the code you referred. It refers to a different database `learn2crack` which might have defined a different table structure. I suggest you read further on that app code to proceed further.